# Looking for rare solo Neil Peart studio recording

Tags: prog-rock

Back in the late 80s I had a 45' which came as some sort of bonus with some other purchase (I'm drawing a blank on what that was) which was a solo song that Neil Peart recorded using a variety of analog and digital drums. It had some tubular bell sounds, as I recall.

He later incorporated pieces of the composition into his larger live solos but I'm unable to find the original recording anywhere. Curious if anyone here has thoughts on where I can locate it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Info from here:

http://www.andrewolson.com/Neil_Peart/catalog/neil_peart_discography_solo.htm

"Pieces of Eight" - Modern Drummer Soundsheet, 1987

```
"Pieces of Eight" was a solo project for Peart to try out his new Ludwig drums (see "The Quest for New Drums") and was a sound supplement included in the May 1987 Modern Drummer.
```

This song showcases Peart's compositional abilities, with him playing his malletKAT and other assorted percussion. The result is dynamic piece that echoes the 7/8 riff "Natural Science" riff in the verses.

During the Hold Your Fire tour, Peart would add the "verse" section of "Pieces of Eight" to his drum solo as call and response between the malletKAT and his acoustic drums. On the Vapor Trails tour, he added the chorus section of "Pieces of Eight."

In the May 1987 Modern Drummer article, "The Quest for New Drums" Peart wrote:

"Like many percussionists, I had long harbored a secret wish to create a piece of music using only percussion instruments, and this looked like the key to that dream! I practiced with the KAT for a few days and then, when I had a free day, recorded a "demo" of a marimba piece I had been working on over the summer.

...The piece is entitled "Pieces Of Eight" because of all the different time signatures it ended up meandering through. I hadn't thought about that too much just playing the marimba, until I had to learn it on drums! With only a day to record it all, I didn't really have time to play it more than a couple of times through, so that, too, was a good challenge.

I find it interesting as a drummer to work with a melodic instrument and think melody as well as rhythm. You can really get into some wild areas! In a way, I wish I hadn't been so obsessed with drums alone in the beginning and had acquired more knowledge of music theory. But I suppose in this day and age you do have to specialize!"

Credits:

Recorded and mixed at Elora Sound Studios

Engineered by Jon Erickson

Technical Assistance by Jim Burgess, Larry Allen, and Tony Geranios

Listen here:

Comment: That's IT! Thanks so much!!